# Atom Editor: Hashtag creates brackets - JavaScript editing

Tags: atom-editor

I must have accidentally toggled an option.

If I type a hashtag `#` inside of quotes, atom automatically appends `{}`.

Example:

Type = what I type

Atom = what Atom actually does

```
Type: "
Atom: ""
Type: #
EXPECTED: "#"
Atom: "#{}"
```

Comment: Atom does this when working in Ruby or CoffeeScript documents for variable interpolation. What language are you working in?

Comment: As the title says, Javascript :) This happens whenever editing a .js file. I have not installed or updated any packages recently that could account for this behaviour either. I must have used some button combo to toggle this or something :S

As a side note: the "grammar" in use is Javascript, not coffee script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/18376) that will hopefully get a fix in one of the next releases. As a workaround, you can disable the new [Tree Sitter Parser](https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter) in the Atom Core Settings:

[image]

Keep in mind that Tree Sitter is the next generation parser for Atom, so once the issue has been resolved, you should enable Tree Sitter again!

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well. Potential workaround are being posted on the Atom message boards [here](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/18376).

**UPDATE:** This issue is getting fixed in the next release. Check out the thread I linked to above