# How can I change which grammar gets used in Atom for ERB?

Tags: atom-editor, grammar

Atom recently stopped highlighting any embedded ruby inside my .html.erb files, so now they look like this:

[image]

However, if I change the grammar being used for the editor file to HTML (Rails) instead of ERB, everything goes back to being highlighted the way it should be:

[image]

But every time I open an ERB page it defaults to using the ERB grammar from the language-ruby package, which doesn't highlight any of the ERB, and I don't want to have to manually change the grammar each time I open an ERB file.

Is there any way to change which grammar Atom uses by default for a given file type? If not, are there any other workarounds to fix this and get ERB to start rendering embedded ruby in color again?

Answer (score 2):

Before we get down to the actual question, how to change the default highlighting of a specific syntax, please check that this isn't related to the new [treesitter parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111502/atom-editor-hashtag-creates-brackets-javascript-editing/53205642#53205642).

If you really want to change the default syntax, you can add the following to your Atom configuration (`config.cson`):

```
"*":
  core:
    customFileTypes:
      "text.html.ruby": [
        "*.erb"
      ]
```

Make sure not to overwrite your existing configuration and nest the `customFileTypes` key correctly, since [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) is an indentation-sensitive format.

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please accept it. [Read how to do that and why it helps others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/259968).